# Rewriting a custom post type causes 404 error in other pages and post types

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, urlslug

This code is used for rewriting url slug of a booking_spots post type

```html
function ns_update_booking_spot_cpt($args, $post_type){
if($post_type == 'booking_spots'){
    $args['has_archive'] = true; 
    $args['rewrite'] = array('slug' => '%sports-category%');
    $args['with_front'] = false; 

}
return $args;
}
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'ns_update_booking_spot_cpt', 10, 2);
```

And for changing the post link i have used this code

```
    add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title_prefix', '__return_false' );
    function keep_product_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    $custom_field_values = get_field( 'Location',$post->ID);
    $value = "";
    foreach($custom_field_values as $custom_field_value ):
    $value = $custom_field_value;
    endforeach;
   if($custom_field_values){
   return str_replace( '%sports-category%' , $value , $post_link );
   }

   return $post_link;

   }
   add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'keep_product_link', 10, 2 );
```

In this Location is acf field name and after saving permalinks
The https://healspots.com/playspots-wp/Coimbatore/sbm-sports-kalapatti-road-kurumbapalayam-coimbatore-2/ is loading properly(booking_spots post ) but all other pages and post are showing 404
For eg
https://healspots.com/playspots-wp/playspots-about-us/
Please Help me to fix this issue

Comment: post_type_link is changing all post types links ? Also this ACF field is for all post types or only for booking_spots ? Do you get value from it for the problem pages ?

Comment: Acf field only for booking_post type not for others, in backend the links are normal like ttps://healspots.com/playspots-wp/playspots-about-us/ but in frontend causing 404 error

Comment: Like i said you are changing all links not just for your custom post so thats the main issue i think.